# 'libdenpli.so : undefined reference to symbol 'Tcl_InitStubs'

Tags: gcc, dll, shared-libraries, undefined-symbol, nm

I am getting `'libdenpli.so : undefined reference to symbol 'Tcl_InitStubs'` while creating executable.

When I check with `nm`, I am getting this output:

```
nm libdenpli.so | grep Tcl_InitStubs
          U denaliTcl_InitStubs
```

I looked at other machine with different platform where it worked fine. And I seen the output with `t`:

```
nm libdenpli.so | grep Tcl_InitStubs
<address> t denaliTcl_InitStubs
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Note that `denaliTcl_InitStubs` doesn't have any obvious relation to the `Tcl_InitStubs` symbol that is undefined — except that it shares 13 characters in the same sequence in the name.  It would appear, however, that there is a difference between the two Denali libraries on the two machines since one defines and the other does not define the `denaliTcl_InitStubs` symbol.

Comment: Is there any way to find which library is defining the symbol in "libdenpli.so" library?

Comment: You'd have to use `nm` (or equivalent) on the shared objects.  There's an option (which varies a bit) that lists the container name on each line of output, so you could use `nm -g -A …shared-objects-or-object-files…` (on macOS or POSIX-ish systems; the `-A` option is POSIX, but macOS also uses `-o` for the job, whereas POSIX uses `-o` to print octal instead of hexadecimal or decimal) and pipe that through `grep` to find where there are references and definitions (though it appears you are missing definitions).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [`nm`'s manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm):

```
       "t" The symbol is in the text (code) section.

       "U" The symbol is undefined.
```

In other words, your `libdenpli.so` uses the symbol, but does not define it -- you need to link to the library that defines that symbol as well.

Since the other system's library seems to define it, maybe there are differences on how the libraries are supposed to be linked with, due to version, platform, build options, etc. Try to take a look at the documentation of the library to see how you are supposed to link to it.

Comment: U is undefined right? it means all the other symbols without "U/u" are defined symbols ?

Comment: See I have one library "libtcl8.4.so" which has those symbols Shown below..                                                                  [lndp@sjfmachine02 lib] nm libtcl8.4.so | grep denaliTcl_InitStubs
00000000000835d0 T denaliTcl_InitStubs
[lndp@sjfmachine02 lib]$ nm libtcl8.4.so | grep denalitclStubsPtr
00000000000d8068 B denalitclStubsPtr                                                 I kept it in one of my paths -L <path> with gcc command. But still facing same issue.

Comment: @jerry: In order to link the library, you need not only the `-L` argument(s) (where to find it) but also the `-l` one(s) (which library to link). Try adding add `-ltcl` (if there is a symlink) or `-ltcl8.4` directly.